# Use awk or sed to remove everything between < >

Tags: ubuntu, awk, sed

I have the following in a txt file:

```
<ol><li><b><a href="/page1/Mark_Yato" title="Mark Yato">Mark Yato</a> ft. MarkAm &amp; <a href="/page1/Giv%C4%93on" title="Givēon">Givēon</a> - <a href="/page1/Mark_Yato:Thuieo" title="Mark Yato:Thuieo">Thuieo</a> (7)</b></li>
<li><b><a href="/page1/The_Central" title="The Central">The Central</a> - <a href="/page1/The_Central:AHTIOe oie" title="The Central:AHTIOe oie">AHTIOe oie</a> (7)</b></li>
<li><b><a href="/page1/Taa_Too_A" title="Taa Too A">Taa Too A</a> - <a href="/page1/Taa_Too_A:ryhwtyw w" title="Taa Too A:ryhwtyw w">ryhwtyw w</a> (8)</b></li>
```

and am trying to make it output as the following:

```
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo
The Central - AHTIOe oie
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w
```

To achieve this, I thought I would try removing '<', '>' and everything between them so it's left with just the list I'm trying to get.

I tried the following sed command already:

```
sed 's/<[^()]*>//g'
```

but this is outputting just the following:

```
(7)
(7)
(8)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix the sed command or translate it into awk if it is better use for that?

Comment: Is your text file actually an HTML document (i.e. a web page)? Or does it really only have snippets like the example?

Comment: Looks like you simply mis-typed `<>` as `()`.

Comment: Use `pup` to parse html

Comment: The pattern `<[^()]*>` tells to match a `<`, then any number of characters (`*`) that are not `(` or `)` (`[^()]`), then a `>`. On the first line, that matches the very first `<`, then _everything_ up to `a>` just before the space and `(7)`. And repeats for the last two tags. The `[^()]` could match the `>` and space too, but it needs to track back to let the `>` be matched too.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 25):

Parsing markup with regular expressions is [notoriously problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/10488700).

While not an issue with your sample data, angle brackets may appear in tag attributes, comments and possibly other places, making regular expressions that match from `<` to `>` unreliable.

You should resort to tools that implement a markup parser.

For instance, using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) (version >= 2.8) with your sample data (without adding the missing `</ol>` tag):

```
$ pandoc -f html -t plain file 
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo (7)

The Central - AHTIOe oie (7)

Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w (8)
```

You may then easily post-process this output as regular text to remove empty lines and other unwanted parts:

```
$ pandoc -f html -t plain file |
  sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*([[:digit:]]*)$//'
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo
The Central - AHTIOe oie
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w
```

Note that, before version 2.8, `pandoc` used to convert any emphasized text to all-caps when generating output in `plain` format. The `<b>` tag in your list items would trigger this behavior (more on this in the [changelog](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/changelog.md#pandoc-28-2019-11-22) or the relevant [commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/d247e9f72e9c9a86cb0053cffc607b5f84f8b3a4) on GitHub).

Depending on your actual input data, a workaround could be to use `markdown` as `pandoc`'s input format, either explicitly:

```bsh
pandoc -f markdown -t plain file
```

or implicitly, considering it is what `pandoc` automatically defaults to (`pandoc -t plain file`).

Comment: I do wonder how often `>` characters appear in the "wrong" places for this in HTML documents in the wild. I mean, I've done some HTML scraping with regexes back when, and never even stopped to think about the possibility. In any case, you could probably write a regex to match tags with attributes inside, it'd just be more hairy. (But just recognizing the tags should still be possible, since I don't think there's any nesting there. Checking if the end tags match the start tags or such would be different, though.)

Comment: @ilkkachu I agree that `>` is unlikely to be found in unexpected places, but I believe that crafting reliable regular expressions is likely not worth the effort (for instance, I just realized that tags don't need to be opened and closed on the same line) - unless the issue at hand came with really specific assumptions/constraints. Also, my point is to encourage "better" practices, under the usual assumption that others will apply what they find in these Q/As to their own, different problems.

Comment: (_"tags don't need to be opened and closed on the same line"_ is ambiguous; I meant that `<` and the corresponding `>` can be on different lines).

Answer (score 10):

You're almost there - regex matches are "greedy", so you need to tell the pattern that the closing `>` character is not allowed inside the pattern.  Put another way, the `[^()]*` portion inside the pattern will match as much text as it can "greedily".  If you don't tell the pattern to exclude the closing `>` from this portion of the pattern, the opening `<` and closing `>` that the Regex uses are not necessarily the ones that are paired from an HTML point of view.

Use this instead:

```bsh
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

This forces the regex to delete every HTML tag, not a bigger block of text that has `<` and `>` at the ends, as well as `<` or `>` in the middle.

Comment: Might break on something like `<span class="<test>">Hello, world</span>`

Answer (score 6):

so this command should do the trick...

```
sed -i 's/<[^>]*>//g' file
```

result file should be this

```
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm &amp; Givēon - Thuieo (7)
The Central - AHTIOe oie (7)
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w (8)
```

From there you can do this

```
sed -i 's/([0-9])//g' file
```

and it should give you the desired output of this

```
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm &amp; Givēon - Thuieo
The Central - AHTIOe oie
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w
```

EDIT: update second command to look neater.

EDIT: Alternative oneliner

```
sed -i 's/<[^>]*>//g;s/([0-9])//g' file
```

Comment: The problem is angle bracket symbols  inside quotes, or quoted items inside angled brackets. May not be a problem in this case but be aware....

Comment: @Stilez wouldn't any such visual angle brackets actually be represented by `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the HTML and so wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: No.  The OP says this is the content of a text file. As a text file, assume the content is literal. If it meant &gt/lt; then the file content would say so.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `php` to strip all HTML tags and to convert the HTML entities back to normal characters:

```
$ <file php -r 'echo htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(file_get_contents("php://stdin")), ENT_HTML5);'
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo (7)
The Central - AHTIOe oie (7)
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w (8)
```

To additionally remove blanks (spaces, tabs) followed by an opening `(`, followed by one or more numbers and a closing `)` at the line endings with `sed`:

```
$ <file php -r 'echo htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(file_get_contents("php://stdin")), ENT_HTML5);' |
    sed 's/[[:blank:]]*([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*)$//'
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo
The Central - AHTIOe oie
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet fo -H file |
xmlstarlet sel -E latin1 -t -v '//li' -nl 2>/dev/null |
xmlstarlet unesc | sed 's/ [^ ]*$//'
```

This uses `xmlstarlet` to convert the HTML fragment to a well-formed HTML document (the 1st command).  It then extracts the value of each `li` node (The 2nd command).  Finally, it decodes any HTML entities (`&amp;` for example).  The final `sed` command just deletes anything after the last space on each line (there are numbers in parentheses that shouldn't be part of the output).

The output given the document in the question:

```
Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo
The Central - AHTIOe oie
Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `lynx`, then with `nolist` option the following command
would work as:

```
lynx -dump -nolist -force_html file | awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+\. /,""); }1'
lynx -dump -nolist -force_html --display-charset=UTF-8 --assume-charset=UTF-8 file | awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+\. /,""); }1'

## Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo (7)
## The Central - AHTIOe oie (7)
## Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w (8)
```

To remove characters from last space, regex `/ [^ ]*$/` would work as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652698/use-awk-or-sed-to-remove-everything-between/652727#652727). To get desired output, the command would be changed to:

```
lynx -dump -nolist -force_html file | awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+\. /,""); sub(/ [^ ]*$/,""); }1'
lynx -dump -nolist -force_html --display-charset=UTF-8 --assume-charset=UTF-8 file | awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+\. /,""); sub(/ [^ ]*$/,""); }1'

## Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo
## The Central - AHTIOe oie
## Taa Too A - ryhwtyw w
```

If file extension is html, then `-force_html` may be omitted in lynx command as suggested by @Căcărău.
The above command may not work properly in some cases. Therefore it is better to include `--display-charset=UTF-8` `--assume-charset=UTF-8` to lynx command because `UTF-8` is common character encoding on internet.

Comment: Not familiar with Lynx. What does that give you over the AWK script by itself?

Comment: @BWhite This gives.first line for instance: `1. Mark Yato ft. MarkAm & Givēon - Thuieo (7)`

Comment: fwiw, use `-force_html` and lynx won't care about the file extensions

Comment: @Căcărău Thanks. And edited.

Comment: You should mention that your awk scripts require GNU awk for `\s` or change each `\s` to `[[:space:]]` and then it'll behave the same in any POSIX awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. I use `gawk` only. Edited.

Comment: You're welcome. If you always test your scripts with both `gawk --lint` and `gawk --posix` before posting them then between them they'll tell you about most (or maybe all) of the places you're using non-POSIX gawk extensions and then you can either say the script is gawk-only or change it to use a POSIX equivalent. Try, for example, `awk --lint -v FS="" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/\s/,"y",1,"foo")}'` and `awk --posix -v FS="" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/\s/,"y",1,"foo")}'`.

Comment: Use **both** `--lint` and `--posix` in separate calls to gawk. They each identify some issues that the other doesn't and when you use them together in single call (e.g. `awk --lint --posix -v FS="" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/\s/,"y",1,"foo")}'`) the `--lint` assumes you want to ONLY check POSIX constructs so the output isn't as useful as you won't get any specific warnings about using gawk extensions.

Answer (score 1):

For all of you regex lovers seeking the perfect match, one that does take into account the `<>`'s inside quotes would be:

```
sed -E 's/<([^">]|"[^"]*")*>//g'
```

Which means: "REPLACE a `<` followed by any number of ((not a `>` or a `"`) OR (a `"`, but then it must be followed by any number of (not a `"`) and then a closing `"`) WITH nothing, globally."

It requires extended regexes (`-E`) to be able to branch (i.e. the "OR").

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having sed remove the contents, I could see using it to insert newlines, followed by an egrep to remove the angled bracket lines.
`sed 's/</\n</g' file | sed 's/>/>\n/g' | egrep -v "<|>"`
First sed puts a return character before opening bracket.  Second sed puts a return character after the closing bracket.  The grep returns all lines without brackets.

Comment: ignore my answer... I didn't take into account the additional brackets inside the lines.